# Matlab optimization toolbox, optimizing hessian

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

Never used this toolbox before, I have a very large problem (i.e. number of variables) to be optimzed. I'm aware it's possible to optimize the hessian computation, which is my issue given the error:

```
Error using eye
Requested 254016x254016 (480.7GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may
take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

But according to this quote (from a forum) it must be possible to optimize the hessian computation:

> If you are going to use the trust-region algorithm, you will need to
>   choose some combination of the options 'Hessian', 'HessMult', and
>   'HessPattern' to avoid full, explicit computation of the Hessian.

I struggle to find examples of this settings, does anyone know?

My problem is a sparse problem, if such information is necessary.

Basically I'm sure there's some extra options to be put in a line like:

```
option = optimoptions(@fminunc,...
    'Display','iter','GradObj','on','MaxIter',30,...
    'ObjectiveLimit',10e-10,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
```

Comment: You have shown no code to optimize. Not even mentioned the function you are using! We can not help if you do not share the relevant information!

Comment: I assume you read the documentation? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html#butpb7p-options

Comment: I think `HessPattern` might be what I'm looking for. But I have no clue how to use it. So @AnderBiguri yes, I read it.

Comment: "I do not know how to use it" is not a question unfortunately. Its what it is explained there in the documentation you read. If you know the non-zero pattern of the Hessian, you can give it there. Otherwise you may need to use a optimization method that does not require a Hessian

Comment: But I don't get it, if I need a matrix to specify the sparsity of the hessian, which is of the same size of the matrix the toolbox is trying to allocate isn't that the same problem?

Comment: No, you give a *sparse* matrix to specify the sparsity of the Hessian. A sparse matrix with 1 non-zero only stores that non-zero and its location.

Comment: Is it a logical matrix?

Comment: Since you're trying to solve 254,000 variables, it doesn't seem that newton-like methods would be a good fit for you. Why not consider some of the gradient-based solvers?

Comment: @Durkee like levenberg-marquadt?

Comment: Levenberg-marquardt is a newton-like method in that it uses the full jacobian. I mean using something like scaled-conjugate-gradient or something which uses the mean of the jacobian and would only have a 1x254,000 derivative vector to traverse. Those operations are much more memory friendly and have much better convergence rates for problems your size. Newton-like methods in general perform poorly on large scale problems.

Comment: I'll give it a go, if the hessian thing doesn't work.

Comment: @user8469759  it is a **sparse matrix**. You can google it as much as I can to understand why these take less memory.

Comment: I meant as a type in matlab. I don't recognize the type "sparse matrix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `'HessPattern',Hstr` to `optimoptions`. An example is given [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/minimization-with-gradient-and-hessian-sparsity-pattern.html) (In this example, `Hstr` is defined in `brownhstr.mat`; you need to calculate your own hessian sparsity pattern matrix `Hstr`).